# PHP Pull Image And Display

Tags: php, gd

I have a PHP file which I have used mod rewrite to make a .jpg extension. I want to grab an image from a url

example: http://msn.com/lol.gif

take the data and then display it in my .jpg with jpeg headers, so as far as the user is concerned it is a normal image. Is this possible and if so can anyone give me some pointers?

Answer (score 2):

If you use a combination of curl and PHP's image manipulation methods, which you can learn about [here](http://www.tutorialized.com/tutorials/PHP/Image-Manipulation/1), will get you to what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

using php GD library:

```
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
$pic = imagecreatefromgif($url);
Imagejpeg($pic);
ImageDestroy($pic);
```

Using Imagick Library:

```
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
$image = new Imagick($url);
$image->setImageFormat( "jpg" );
echo $image;
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on you needs (do you need to manipulate the image?), you can just open the remote file and output it to the browser.

Check out the documentation on the [readfile](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) function and the [http wrapper](http://us.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.http.php).